# Basic probability exercise { looking for explanation }

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

10 different balls are put inside 4 different boxes. What is the probability that exactly 2 boxes remain empty ?

Although I have an answer I was looking for explanation for this solution :

$ P(A) = \frac{\binom{4}{2} * (2^{10} - 2)}{4^{10}} $

Comment: Select two boxes distribute 10 balls between them ignoring the cases when either of the selected boxes is empty ..... Divide it by total cases which is trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways in which a pair of boxes can be selected as 'empty' boxes. If these two boxes are empty there are $2^{10}$ possible ways in which $10$ balls can be placed in the remaining boxes. But we must subtract the $2$ cases where one of the remaining two boxes is also empty. To get a probability associated with this event, we divide by the total number of arrangements which is $4^{10}$.

Comment: that's what i'm looking for, thanks man !